# Select cards from the Card Deck

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

**How many ways are there to pick 2 different cards from a standard 52 cards deck such that the first card is a spade and the second card is not a Queen?**

Answer:

**Case I)**

First card is not Queen of spade and the other card is any card but not queen.
13-1 * (52-1-4) = 12 *47

**Case II)**

First card is Queen of spade  and the other card is any card but not queen.
1 * (52-4) = 1 * 48

**Total ways are: 12*47 + 48 ??**

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that answer.

Comment: Me too. Maybe you should write $ 1 * (52 - 1 - 3) $ as the first part of the second formula, to indicate you took out a card and that the card you took out was a queen so there are only 3 bad cards now.

Comment: 1 * (52-4).... I think it should be 1 * (52-3).. coz only three queen cards remaining after queen of spade.

Comment: @RajSharma Yes, but those three queens are among the $52-1$ cards remaining after the queen of spades was picked.

Comment: sorry.. I forgot that you are right.

Comment: Can you give solution in mathematics way? because I am not able to write..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your answer is correct: $12 \times 47 + 48 = \boxed{612}$.

Another way of getting the same answer is that there are $13$ spades and $48$ non-queens, $13 \times 48 = 624$. Then you subtract out the times that we picked the same card twice, which is once for every non-queen spade, of which there are $12$. So $624 - 12 = \boxed{612}$.